# Which clause(s) does といい modify in this sentence?

Tags: translation, verbs, conditionals, reading-comprehension, modification

> 自然な話し方で話せるようになるためには、多くの日本人と色々な場面で話したり、日本の映画やドラマを見て、どんな場面で、どんな人が、どんな相手に、どんな話し方をしているかをよく観察するといいでしょう。

This is from the first reading of Tobira's second chapter. I actually have two questions:

1. Which clause or verbs does といい modify? Does it modify only 「どんな場面で、どんな人が、どんな相手に、どんな話し方をしているかをよく観察する」, or does it also modify 「日本の映画やドラマを見て」and「多くの日本人と色々な場面で話したり」?
2. 話す and 見る connected to 観察する differently; the first uses たり, while the second uses て-form. Is this allowed? Why was this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Both 「多くの日本人と色々な場面で話したり」and 「日本の映画やドラマを見て、どんな場面で、どんな人が、どんな相手に、どんな話し方をしているかをよく観察する」

2.Because 日本の映画やドラマを見て connects the following phrase. It means "When you watch Japanese dramas and movies, you should observe ～"

Comment: Ah, so I had mistakenly separated 「日本の映画やドラマを見て」 from 「どんな場面で、どんな人が、どんな相手に、どんな話し方をしているかをよく観察する 」. But how do I know when the て-form means "when" rather than "and"? And why did 「観察したりする」 not end the sentence?

Comment: Because it wants to mean "should(といいでしょう。)".

Comment: My apologies. I meant before といいでしょう (i.e. 観察したりするといいでしょう).

Comment: My answer for your first question is that  you can judge from the context. The one for your second question is that last たり can be omitted. For example, 私は、勉強したり、遊んだり、スポーツをしたりするのが好きです is the same meaning as 私は、勉強したり、遊んだり、スポーツをするのが好きです.

Comment: If I encountered another such construct like 「Aたり、Bて、C」, can I at least be certain that A and B can be parsed independently (even if B and C might not)? What about 「Aて、Bたり、C」?

Comment: I think you shouldn't think it by the form of a sentence but the context.